# Почему результат не меняется?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Вообщем, я использую Beautifulsoup(красивый суп) для парсинга ссылок с  OLX
мой код рабочий, но результат при повторном запуске скрипта не меняется

Вот мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

#детский мир

url = 'https://www.olx.ua/detskiy-mir/?search%5Bpaidads_listing%5D=1'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
quotes = soup.find('div', {'class': 'space rel'}).find('a').get('href')

urls = quotes.replace(' ', '')
print(urls)
```

Получается как то так

[image: Вот такой результат при повторном запуске скрипта]

Можно сделать так что бы каждый раз была новая ссылка?

Comment: Ну, там случайным образом ссылки выдаются, но при этом они могут повторно выдаваться. Что вы хотите, чтобы в этом случае происходило?

Comment: @CrazyElf Что бы каждый раз были разные ссылки? Так ведь можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте с помощью модуля `random` (его нужно установить командой `pip install random2`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

from random import randint


url = 'https://www.olx.ua/detskiy-mir/?search%5Bpaidads_listing%5D=1'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
quotes = soup.find_all('a', class_='marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink') #Ищем все товары на странице


print(quotes[randint(0, len(quotes))].attrs['href']) #Выводи случайный элемент
```

Comment: AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Я исправил код. Попробуйте так.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает

Answer (score 0):

А что должно меняться? если страница не изменилась то и результат будет таким же. Вам показывает только первую найденную ссылку. Вам нужно использовать `soup.findall()`, тогда вы получите все ссылки на странице.